# Apply CSS/ javascript after jquery replaceWith

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, refresh, partial-page-refresh

I'm replacing a row in a html table after a ajax request.
After a successful request, I receive a partial html piece that I replace with the current row.

> $("#id").replaceWith(response)

Now I added a checkbox input field and I pimped it using this css and js library [Bootstrap Switch](https://github.com/nostalgiaz/bootstrap-switch)

So after I replace the row I only see a plain normal input checkbox. And not the nice toggle.
If I refresh the page the toggle is rendered.

Can anybody help me and point me to the problem of this issue?
I tried to use trigger('create') on the row and the parent.

This is the code I use for updating the table, like I mentioned it's only doing a replaceWith.

```
processRecord = (barCode, random_id) ->
  postParams = { barCode: barCode, ran_id: random_id }

  $.ajax
    url: '/scans'
    type: 'post'
    data: postParams

    success: (response, textStatus, xhr) ->
      $("#" + random_id).replaceWith(response)
      $("#scans").trigger('create')
```

I've been digging around the bootstrap switch code. The init method will cause additional html to be added to the input checkbox after rendering. This isn't happening when I do a replace. Take a look here: https://github.com/nostalgiaz/bootstrap-switch/blob/master/static/js/bootstrapSwitch.js#L14

Thanks

Comment: If you have JavaScript events attached to the element, you  probably need to delegate them to a parent element instead, or else run them anew once the `replaceWith` is completed. Without more of your code, it's impossible for us to help you further.

Comment: Can you try $("#table_id_or_class").trigger('create');

Comment: The trigger action doesn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the switch plugin again after replacing the element.

```
success: (response, textStatus, xhr) ->
  $("#" + random_id).replaceWith(response)

      // assuming #scans is the parent of inputs
      var sc = $("#scans").

  if (!sc.hasClass('has-switch')) { // this is to prevent stacking
     sc['bootstrapSwitch'](); // if has-switch is not found, use switch plugin
  }
```